# how to find unique line in a txt file?

Tags: powershell

I have a LARGE list of hashes. I need to find out which ones only appear once as most are duplicates.

EX: the last line `238db2.....` only appears once

```
ac6b51055fdac5b92934699d5b07db78
ac6b51055fdac5b92934699d5b07db78
7f5417a85a63967d8bba72496faa997a
7f5417a85a63967d8bba72496faa997a
1e78ba685a4919b7cf60a5c60b22ebc2
1e78ba685a4919b7cf60a5c60b22ebc2
238db202693284f7e8838959ba3c80e8
```

I tried the following that just listed one of each of the doubles, not just identifying the one that only appeared once

```
foreach ($line in (Get-Content "C:\hashes.txt" | Select-Object -Unique)) {
  Write-Host "Line '$line' appears $(($line | Where-Object {$_ -eq $line}).count) time(s)."
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If nothing, I'd suggest taking a look at [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.3) and [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.3) to get you going.

Comment: I have tried proably about 30 variations of different things and thought it woud clutter this question listing them. but basically used get-content and a for loop to iterate through the lines but keep just grabbing the unique ones including one of each of the doubles

Comment: Open a file stream using `File.OpenRead` then use a `StreamReader` to read each line one at a time and add them to a `HashSet`. A `HashSet` discards all duplicates so you don't need to worry about checking it first. Then use `File.WriteAllLines` to write it all back to a file. Note that this won't load the entire file into memory, but all unique strings will at one point be loaded into memory at the same time. Trying to come up with a solution that doesn't do this would be a lot more difficult.

Comment: to be clear im trying to delete both occurences of a hash if it has a duplicate. I need to find out which one in the file does not have a duplicate

Comment: So then make two sets, one for duplicates and one for unique. If it's already in the unique set, remove it and add it to the duplicates set. If it's in the duplicates set, don't add it to the unique one.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Hashtable and a StreamReader.
The StreamReader reads the file line-by-line and the Hashtable will store that line as Key and in its Value state $true (if this is a duplicate) or $false (if it is unique)

```
$reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new('D:\Test\hashes.txt')
$hash   = @{}
while($null -ne ($line = $reader.ReadLine())) {
    $hash[$line] = $hash.ContainsKey($line)
}

# clean-up the StreamReader
$reader.Dispose()

# get the unique line(s) by filtering for value $false
$result = $hash.Keys | Where-Object {-not $hash[$_]}
```

Given your example, $result will contain `238db202693284f7e8838959ba3c80e8`

Answer (score 1):

- Given that you're dealing with a *large* file, [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) is best avoided.
- A [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement with the `-File` parameter allows efficient line-by-line processing, and given that duplicates appear to be *grouped together* already, they can be detected by keeping a running count of identical lines.

```bash
$count = 0 # keeps track of the count of identical lines occurring in sequence
switch -File 'C:\hashes.txt' {
  default {
    if ($prevLine -eq $_ -or $count -eq 0) { # duplicate or first line.
      if ($count -eq 0) { $prevLine = $_ }
      ++$count 
    }
    else { # current line differs from the previous one.
      if ($count -eq 1) { $prevLine } # non-duplicate -> output
      $prevLine = $_
      $count = 1
    }
  }
}
if ($count -eq 1) { $prevLine } # output the last line, if a non-duplicate.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$values = Get-Content .\hashes.txt # Read the values from the hashes.txt file

$groups = $values | Group-Object | Where-Object { $_.Count -eq 1 } # Group the values by their distinct values and filter for groups with a single value

foreach ($group in $groups) {
    foreach ($value in $group.Values) {
        Write-Host "$value" # Output the value of each group
    }
}
```

To handle very large files you could try this.

```
$chunkSize = 1000 # Set the chunk size to 1000 lines
$lineNumber = 0  # Initialize a line number counter

# Use a do-while loop to read the file in chunks
do {
    # Read the next chunk of lines from the file
    $values = Get-Content .\hashes.txt | Select-Object -Skip $lineNumber -First $chunkSize

    # Group the values by their distinct values and filter for groups with a single value
    $groups = $values | Group-Object | Where-Object { $_.Count -eq 1 }

    foreach ($group in $groups) {
        foreach ($value in $group.Values) {
            Write-Host "$value" # Output the value of each group
        }
    }

    # Increment the line number counter by the chunk size
    $lineNumber += $chunkSize
} while ($values.Count -eq $chunkSize)
```

Or this

```
# Create an empty dictionary
$dict = New-Object System.Collections.Hashtable

# Read the file line by line
foreach ($line in Get-Content .\hashes.txt) {
    # Check if the line is already in the dictionary
    if ($dict.ContainsKey($line)) {
        # Increment the value of the line in the dictionary
        $dict.Item($line) += 1
    } else {
        # Add the line to the dictionary with a count of 1
        $dict.Add($line, 1)
    }
}

# Filter the dictionary for values with a count of 1
$singles = $dict.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq 1 }

# Output the values of the single items
foreach ($single in $singles) {
    Write-Host $single.Key
}
```

Comment: Your 2nd example looks flawed. If a hash value appears at the end of one chunk and at the beginning of the next one, it will be listed twice.